# Customization of autocomplete in sales order line entry

Tags: acumatica

I would like to know would it be possible to customize the "auto-complete" at the sales order line entry.
For example, I wish the user can see the stock item ID, description and status at the 'suggestion' or 'auto-complete' lines.[image: SOEntryAutoComplete]

Comment: I think that is just the description field of that field. There is only one description field. If you want to modify that you could try to add a cache extension field that concats the fields and use this new field as the field description field. If no one else answers i could try to give an example if possible at a later date

Comment: It is possible that the Hint feature will not execute the attribute and attempt to fetch values from database instead. If I modify the description field with FieldSelecting in graph it will show up correctly in selector dialog but the hint will remain unchanged.

Comment: The approach at the bottom here could work: https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/09/custom-selector-attribute.html